# Best practice for saving external API data in the background using Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I am building an application where users can connect to an external API and it will pull in updates from a 3rd party API in the background (while the user isn't on the website). It will then store any updates within the database. I am confident with the programming, I have a 'best practice' query of where to put the actual saving logic the 'Laravel way'. My thoughts are as follows:

- Define a schedule which runs every hour. Within the 'schedule()' function I simply dispatch jobs for each user who needs data updating within that hour. Or even it could just dispatch a Job 'UpdateData' for every user (it's not really relevant for this query).
- Now, within the Job class, I could just add all the API calls and database logic directly into the handle() function. This might be correct, but it doesn't feel 'best practice' to me.

The only other option I can think of is creating a function on the Model, User3rdPartyData->updateFromAPI() and call this from the handle() function. But again this doesn't feel 'best practice' either.

Any advice on how to structure this logic the 'Laravel way' would be welcome. I'm finding it hard to Google an answer.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what the question is, but background processes are usually found in `App\Console\Kernel.php` where you can initiate by running `php artisan schedule:run` command. Learn more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling):

Comment: Thanks @AntonyMN yeah, the first step in my flow above uses 'php artisan schedule:run' to run the query every hour.